# Why C++ default initialization doesn't zero-initialize non-class type members

Tags: c++, initialization

why the standard decides to do nothing for non-class type members during a [default initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) but performs [zero initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) during [value initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization)?

Would it be safer if zero initialization is always performed on non-clss type memebers?

Comment: You don't pay for what you  don't use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the basic principles of design in the language is that you should not pay for something you don't need. If you want your members initialized, you can ask the compiler to do so, but if you don't want that, the cost won't be forced onto you.

Default initialization will only initialize those things that *need* to be initialized, that is, the members that have a non-trivial default constructor, as that constructor is meant to set some invariants that are important for the object. Note that the distinction is not class-type vs. fundamental type, but rather whether there is a trivial constructor or not:

```
struct POD { int a; int b; int c; };
struct V { virtual void f(); };
struct Type {
   std::string str;       // default initialization calls default constructor
   V           obj;       //  " calls default constructor: vptr must be set
   POD         pod;       // default initialization leaves this untouched
};
```

Comment: I see, but just for argument sake, in reality how much more would it cost to always do zero initialization? Will all compiler implementations respect this rule?

Comment: @swang: The value of the member is undefined, so the implementation can do what it wishes. Some implementations in debug mode accept the cost and initialize it to 0 (or some garbage easy to identify value). As the standard makes no promises of what the value will be, the implementation can make it be anything. What is the cost? In most cases probably small, but as soon as there is one case where it will be noticeable, you cannot force your choice on the users. Most implementations do follow the rule (i.e. won't initialize) in optimized builds.

Answer (score 4):

If you're going to initialize the data yourself later, then you don't want to pay for initializing the memory to zero only to have it overwritten.

Comment: so it's purely for efficiency? then why different for value initialization?

Comment: @swang: So that you can pay for it if you want it.

Answer (score 3):

I've never heard Bjarne, or another member of the standards committee, say that language safety is a guiding principle of C++ language design. Certainly, it is for Java and other languages, but the C++ language designers are more likely to favour efficiency:

> C++ is lean and mean. The underlying principle is that you don't pay for what you don't use.

-[Bjarne Stroustrop](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/1356)

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be safer if zero initialization is always performed on non-clss type memebers?

No.

It is safer, in debug configurations, to have a trap representation that loudly complains. Not initialising a value is often a symptom of a deeper problem, so masking that by zero-initialising and carrying on with incorrect data makes problems harder to diagnose.